# İnflater error Edittext while version has changed

Tags: android, android-edittext, inflate-exception

I am writing Android app. My app is working purely on version 7.0 of Android. But I remembered that I have to change my minSdkNumer for low phones get benefit from my app. When I am trying to launch my app on API 21. It gives me the error message. I thought that my mistake is in Edittext so that I have changed. But It still doesn't work. How can I fix it? By the way: There is no mistake in back_input. I tried to delete and launch. It does not work.

Here is giris_ekranı.layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".giris_ekrani"
    android:background="#FAB300">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_lyt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_logo"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_figur"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/user100" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/kullanici"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/back_input"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:hint="Kullanıcı Adınız"
            android:lines="1"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:textColor="#17202A"

            android:textColorHint="#FFFF"
            android:textSize="18dp" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/sifre"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/back_input"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:hint="Şifre"
            android:lines="1"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:textColor="#17202A"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFF"
            android:textSize="18dp" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_giris"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buton"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:text="Giriş Yap"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/arama"
            android:textSize="23dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_ziyaret"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:text="@string/ziyaret_i_olarak_giri_yap"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"


            android:background="@drawable/none"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

            android:textColor="#FFFF"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnuyelik"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:text="Kayıt Ol"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"


            android:background="@drawable/none"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

            android:textColor="#FFFF"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnsifre_unuttum"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:text="Şifremi Unuttum"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:background="@drawable/none"

            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFF"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

My first activity :`

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class giris_ekrani extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "giris_ekrani";
EditText kullanıcı_edittext ;
EditText sifre_edittext ;
Button giris_button ;
Button ziyaret_button ;
Button kayıt_ol_button ;
Button sifremi_unuttum_button ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_giris_ekrani);
        kullanıcı_edittext =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.kullanici);
        sifre_edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sifre);
     giris_button =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_giris);
        ziyaret_button =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ziyaret);
        kayıt_ol_button =    (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnuyelik);
        sifremi_unuttum_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnsifre_unuttum);

        giris_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
Intent bottom_bar_intent = new Intent(giris_ekrani.this ,bottom_bar.class);
startActivity(bottom_bar_intent);

                //  registir();


            }



        });

        kayıt_ol_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent kayıt_ekranı_ıntent = new Intent(giris_ekrani.this,kayit_ekrani.class);
                startActivity(kayıt_ekranı_ıntent);
            }
        });

        sifremi_unuttum_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent sifremi_unuttum_ıntent = new Intent(giris_ekrani.this,sifremi_unuttum.class);
startActivity(sifremi_unuttum_ıntent);
            }
        });




    }

}`
```

Here is my log cat :

```
05-03 23:46:41.955 4134-4134/something.about.berkay.isim E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: something.about.berkay.isim, PID: 4134
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{something.about.berkay.isim/something.about.berkay.isim.giris_ekrani}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class EditText
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class EditText
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at something.about.berkay.isim.giris_ekrani.onCreate(giris_ekrani.java:22)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "something.about.berkay.isim:drawable/back_input" (7f08005f)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f08005f a=-1 r=0x7f08005f}
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2390)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2330)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3730)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:634)
    at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:65)
    at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:61)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:64)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:60)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createEditText(AppCompatViewInflater.java:191)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:113)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1035)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1092)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
    at something.about.berkay.isim.giris_ekrani.onCreate(giris_ekrani.java:22) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

My gradle :

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 15
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'





    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.3.1'

    compile 'com.github.sd6352051.niftydialogeffects:niftydialogeffects:1.0.0@aar'

    compile 'com.mindorks:paracamera:0.2.2'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: can you update your question with code for your activity?

Comment: Surely . Wait a minute please. By the way I have totally 6 activities.

Comment: Looks like problem with setting drawable. can you update your question with layout.xml for `giris_ekrani` ?

Comment: I did it. Yes I have too many drawable item in my project.

Comment: what are to contents of `back_input` in drawable folder?

Comment: to giving softy color background. I deleted but there is still exception.  İt "s full name back_input.png(v24).

Comment: If not required, remove all `back_input`. The error says, `back_input` is not a drawable. Clean and rebuild your app. If this doesn't help, update this information in your question so that someone else could help you out.

Comment: ok I am updating my question. By the way thanks for  your labour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my exception with traditional ways.

> android:textColor="#FFFF" ---> must be android:textColor="#FFFFFF".